# Andors-trail (opensource game) UML Diagrams

Tags: android, uml

i would like to study this open-source game.
The problem is that it has a lot of classes and without diagrams would be very hard for me to understand it fully.
I would like to know if there's someone who already reverse-engineered it and if it's possible to have those diagrams 
The sources can be found on googlecode here:

http://code.google.com/p/andors-trail/

Comment: I am on a 3G connection and here on this computer i have only IntelliJ Idea CE which has diagrams disabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a french program :

http://www.topcased.org/index.php?idd_projet_pere=52&Itemid=60

But use the RCP version, the eclipse plugin isn't really stable.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i will look in the future, but as i said in the comment i am on a 3G connection and would take age (and money!) to download 300+ megs!